# jQuery - this.option becomes undefined in load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, this

I'm trying to alter a Plugin a little bit, here's the Prototype function, I've marked what lines I've added.

OK, so my problem happens inside the img-load function I've added. I've surrounded the old code with one to assure that the script waits until the image has loaded.
The problem is, that "this" inside the load-function is not connected with the one outside. I've tried giving the load function a parameter but apparently it's not working or I'm doing something wrong.

Do you know an easy way to sort-of inherit "this"? I don'T really know what else to do.

```
Plugin.prototype._fade = function(number) {
  var $element, currentSlide, next, slidesControl, value,
    _this = this;
  $element = $(this.element);
  this.data = $.data(this);
  if (!this.data.animating && number !== this.data.current + 1) {
    $.data(this, "animating", true);
    currentSlide = this.data.current;
    if (number) {
      number = number - 1;
      value = number > currentSlide ? 1 : -1;
      next = number;
    } else {
      value = this.data.direction === "next" ? 1 : -1;
      next = currentSlide + value;
    }
    if (next === -1) {
      next = this.data.total - 1;
    }
    if (next === this.data.total) {
      next = 0;
    }

    this._setActive(next);
    slidesControl = $(".slidesjs-control", $element);



    var nxtImg = $(slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")")).find("img:eq(0)"); // added
    if ( nxtImg.attr("longdesc") !== undefined ) {  // added
      nxtImg.attr("src", nxtImg.attr("longdesc")); // added
      nxtImg.removeAttr("longdesc"); // added
    } // added


    nxtImg.load(function(){ // added
      slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
        display: "block",
        left: 0,
        zIndex: 0
      });
      this.options.callback.start(currentSlide + 1);
      if (this.options.effect.fade.crossfade) {
        return slidesControl.children(":eq(" + this.data.current + ")").stop().fadeOut(this.options.effect.fade.speed, (function() {
          slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
            zIndex: 10
          });
          $.data(_this, "animating", false);
          $.data(_this, "current", next);
          return _this.options.callback.complete(next + 1);
        }));
      } else {
        slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
          display: "none"
        });
        return slidesControl.children(":eq(" + currentSlide + ")").stop().fadeOut(this.options.effect.fade.speed, (function() {
          slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").stop().fadeIn(_this.options.effect.fade.speed).css({
            zIndex: 10
          });
          $.data(_this, "animating", false);
          $.data(_this, "current", next);
          return _this.options.callback.complete(next + 1);
        }));
      }
    }); // added



  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're capturing the this in a closure variable "_this". Isn't that working?

Comment: Actually you're right! I just exchanged the this with _this and now everything works. Simple as that, yet I couldn't figure it out by myself. Thanks!